# apptivate.ms 2.0 voting bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, apptivate.ms

At the present time, there are only 3 apps.

I voted, but somehow double clicked.  There was a momentary message about waiting for 3 seconds between votes, so I waited and voted again.  Then I voted and voted and voted some more, ignoring the warnings (errors).

I submitted 3 votes for KidZone in total.

Just in case the other votes came from other users, I went to CupCake Match and basically just voted on it many many times.  After many clicks, the *thumbs up* would go back to being an outline instead of being solid.  The count however has kept going up.  Then I'd wait 3 seconds and click on it again to properly vote.

Finally, I end up with the screenshot at the end which I'm sure concludes that all my votes counted. There aren't even 20 apps to vote on yet!  At time of writing, the vote tally is

```
Cupcake : 21
Kidzone : 5
Meanings: 5
```

### (Please don't ban me!)

<sub><sup>I'm just a messenger</sup></sub>

[image]

*p/s - I may have missed the memo that apps can be voted more than once (per day)...*

Comment: Whoops. We're looking into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this - I was able to reproduce the issue on the site.

Turns out that there was a missing constraint on the voting table.

I cleared out all duplicate votes, added the missing constraint and you can now no longer voter multiple times for an app.

Please try to break it some more and let us know ;)